# PostgreSQL equivalent of Oplog Tailing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, logging, real-time, analytics

Is there an equivalent process similar to oplog tailing for MongoDB in PostgreSQL? I find it very useful in MongoDB for real-time analytics and building out dashboards on what is going on in the DB by peeking at the log. Unfortunately MongoDB is not useful for my particular DB needs. I'm looking really for a legitimate, non-hackish, way of doing it. This would be put in a production environment and I can't cause more problems than it's worth down the line.

Thanks in advance and lets try to not make this a NO-SQL vs RDBMS debate.

Comment: Seems it could be possible http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-notify.html https://gist.github.com/quiver/4240546

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.4 and newer you can use the `test_decoding` plugin via `pg_recvlogical` to stream changes from a replication slot.

In 9.3 and newer `pg_xlogdump` can decode the transaction log segments, but that means you have to capture and dump each segment, and it really requires WAL archiving to be enabled in order to be practical.

You should also look at:

- The `pg_stat_statements` extension
- The built-in `pg_stat_activity` view
- The built-in `pg_stat_..` views like `pg_stat_user_indexes`, etc.

Comment: this answer is outdated as of 2019 - Postgres now has LISTEN and NOTIFY capabilities

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman That's nonsensical. LISTEN and NOTIFY far predate logical decoding. But that did not appear to be what the original post wanted.