# PostgreSQL: operations logging

Tags: postgresql

I have a need to ensure all data modifications (insert/update/delete) are captured in my database. Bigger picture, a procedure will read each modification and map that information to a specific message structure, then add it to a queue like Kafka. I'm not sure the best way to do that though. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540503/postgresql-equivalent-of-oplog-tailing-in-mongodb) hints at using the `test_decoding` plugin. Other resources point toward WAL and querying replication slots, but I don't have a need for either archiving WALs or actually replicating my data. I just need a log of everything that happened to that data. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM operations_log;

> | query                                                              |
> | INSERT INTO users (id, name, bio) VALUES (1, 'pat', 'a person')    |
> | UPDATE users SET name = 'Pat' WHERE id = 1                         |
```

How do folks manage this need in PostgreSQL? Is replication or WAL archiving necessary to get this benefit?

Answer (score -1):

I generally solve this with an after trigger on the table, and then insert the old row, along with a timestamp and any other relevant information into another audit table.

So, to take your users table as an example, I would create a users_audit
table:

```
create table users_audit (
    ts timestamptz default current_timestamp,
    like users
);
```

And then a trigger function

```
create function users_audit_trigger() returns trigger
language plpgsql as $$
insert into users_audit values (current_timestamp, OLD.*);
$$
```

Finally the actual trigger...

```
create trigger users_audit_tg after update or delete on users
for each row execute procedure users_audit_trigger();
```

The above is untested, and you may want to log more information,
such as the user doing the update or the actual operation of an
update or delete, so the details will likely be a bit different.

You can use logical replication to do some or all of this on a different
server, but the basic idea remains the same.